# Triggering WhenEvent as a result of WhenEvent

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, bugs, symbolic

I'm attempting to solve a dead-simple differential equation with events:

```
y[t] /. First@DSolve[
   {y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y''[t] == 0,
    WhenEvent[t == 1, y'[t] -> y'[t] + 1],
    WhenEvent[t == 2, y'[t] -> y'[t] - 1],
    WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, y'[t] -> 0],
    WhenEvent[y'[t] > 1/2, y'[t] -> y'[t] - 1/2]},
   y[t], {t, 0, 4}]
```

The result is not what I expected, the `y'[t] > 1/2` event does't trigger:

> $\begin{cases}
>  0 & 0\leq t\leq 1 \\
>  t-1 & 1<t\leq 2 \\
>  1 & 2<t\leq 4 \\
>  \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

I can work around this condition with a hack which includes the change in `y'[t]` whenever it may change accordingly:

```
y[t] /. First@DSolve[
   {y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y''[t] == 0,
    WhenEvent[t == 1, y'[t] -> y'[t] + 1 + If[-1/2 < y'[t] < 1/2, -1/2, 0]],
    WhenEvent[t == 2, y'[t] -> y'[t] - 1],
    WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, y'[t] -> 0]},
   y[t], {t, 0, 4}]
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  0 & 0\leq t\leq 1 \\
>  \frac{t-1}{2} & 1<t\leq 2 \\
>  \frac{3-t}{2} & 2<t\leq 3 \\
>  0 & 3<t\leq 4 \\
>  \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

This is the answer I expected.

Is there a way to make the first differential equation specification work like the second does, and if not, should this be considered a bug?

Comment: I always assumed that `WhenEvents` would be triggered only by the differential equations, not by another `WhenEvent`.  Otherwise I could imagine an infinite loop between different events could occur.  But I couldn't find this in the documentation.

Comment: @ChrisK This also came to my mind. Such a limitation would prevent solving a large family of well-behaved systems, though. Sadly static reasoning about sensibility of an input is not realistic, so if the non-recursion is really a feature, it should be clearly documented.

Comment: @kirma  Do you plan to report this matter as a bug?

Comment: @bbgodfrey I guess I'll write a bug report later today...

Comment: @kirma  Great.  There seem to be several interrelated bugs here.  I just added a sentence on `"DetectionMethod" -> "Sign"` to the answer, which identifies still another problem.  I can email to you my notebook, if you wish.

Comment: @kirma  I shall clean up the notebook and send it to you in a few hours.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is more an extended comment than an answer.  I first tried as a work-around to set the `"DetectionMethod"` option in `WhenEvent`, but doing so caused `DSolve` not to evaluate. (Even `"DetectionMethod" -> "Sign"` causes `DSolve` not to execute, even though `"Sign"` is the default detection method!) I then tried introducing a discrete variable,

```
DSolveValue[{y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, a[0] == 0, y''[t] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[t == 1, {y'[t] -> y'[t] + 1, a[t] -> 1}], 
    WhenEvent[t == 2, y'[t] -> y'[t] - 1], 
    WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, y'[t] -> 0], 
    WhenEvent[a[t] == 1, {[y'[t] -> y'[t] - 1/2, a[t] -> 0}]},  
    y[t], {t, 0, 4}, DiscreteVariables -> {a}]
```

but doing so yielded the same result first presented in the question.

I then investigated how `NDSolve` would handle the same equations.

```
NDSolveValue[{y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y''[t] == 0,
    WhenEvent[t == 1, y'[t] -> y'[t] + 1],
    WhenEvent[t == 2, y'[t] -> y'[t] - 1],
    WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, y'[t] -> 0],
    WhenEvent[y'[t] > 1/2, y'[t] -> y'[t] - 1/2]},
    y[t], {t, 0, 4}];
Plot[%, {t, 0, 4}, AxesLabel -> {t, y}, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}]
```

[image]

which is numerically the same as the `DSolve` answer.  The `"DetectionMethod"` option in `WhenEvent` does not prevent `NDSolve` from evaluating, but it does not give the desired answer either.  However, introducing a discrete variable,

```
NDSolveValue[{y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, a[0] == 0, y''[t] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[t == 1, {y'[t] -> y'[t] + 1, a[t] -> 1}], 
    WhenEvent[t == 2, y'[t] -> y]'[t] - 1], 
    WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, y'[t] -> 0], 
    WhenEvent[a[t] == 1, {y'[t] -> y'[t] - 1/2, a[t] -> 0}]},  
    y[t], {t, 0, 4}, DiscreteVariables -> {a}]

Plot[%, {t, 0, 4}, AxesLabel -> {t, y}, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 15}]
```

[image]

now produces the desired answer.  That `DSolve` and `NDSolve` yield different answers for the same equations and the same options does seem like a bug to me.